# How to increase memory available for chromium in chrome-aws-lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

I collect the data using puppeteer and chrome-aws-lambda. I plan to push it to AWS Lambda but while testing locally I get an error:

```
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
```

when I call for `waitForSelector`.

I've some posts that mentioned there is a chance that chrome process gets too little memory within the docker. The question is: how to get it more memory? I also read that `disable-dev-shm-usage` may help, but it doesn't. That's how I do it now (the last line is where error happens):

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            args: [...chromium.args, `--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`, '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
            headless: chromium.headless,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.authenticate({ username, password });
        await page.goto(MY_URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
        await page.click(SUBMIT_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForSelector('#myDiv')
            .then(() => console.log('got it')).
            catch((e)=>console.log('Error happens: '+ e));
```

UPDATE: more info on local setup:

I run it locally using `sam local start-api`.
Here is the content of my `template.yaml` (just a slightly updated `hello-world` template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  samnode

  Sample SAM Template for samnode
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Resources:
  
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 4096
      Layers:
        - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:22'
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: can you provide more details about how are you running on local, like are you using SAM or some other framework?

Comment: @GSSwain, thanks! I just added an update with this info to the post.

Comment: Remove the AWS Account number from the template in the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: if you mean this: `764866452798 `, it is just an id of publicly available chrome-aws-lambda. Can't see any other account number here

Comment: So was it a memory issue or something else? It would be great if you can add what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   MemorySize: 4096
> ```

You have already configured 4GB memory for the Lambda and it should be more than enough to load couple of pages. If you still feel this is the issue, you can increase the memory upto 10240. I suspect the error may not be related to memory.

To verify, you can do the following to see if the Lambda is actually getting the specified memory.

Run the lambda in Eager mode (This keeps the lambda running on local even if there are no active requests)

`sam local start-api --warm-containers EAGER`

Now run the following command to track the memory consumption

`docker stats`

You can send a request to your local api now and track the memory consumption.
If you see less than 4GB memory allocated to your lambda function, then update the Docker resources and ensure you allocate appropriate memory to Docker.

Update Docker Resources (Increase memory)

- [Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)
- [Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)

Try out different versions of `chrome-aws-lambda` (may be using a [local layer with SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/)).
I would also run the same block of code on local using `Puppeteer` by disabling the headless mode and verify the selector the code is waiting for is actually available.

- Install the `puppeteer` dependency.
- Update the code to use `puppeteer` instead of `chrome-aws-lambda`

`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');`

- Disable headless mode

`browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});`

- Now run the file with `node <replace-with-your-file-name.js>` e.g. if the file name is somejsfile.js then the command would be `node somefile.js`

Hope this helps you proceed further.

Comment: it still fails when I run it locally, but works fine when I deploy it to AWS Lambda. Can you drop me a message to chapkovski@gmail.com, I would be very interested if you can help me solving this (I'll compensate, for sure).